# Bug on curve related rates problem

Tags: calculus, derivatives

Problem:
A bug is crawling along the curve defined by the equation $x^2=y^3+3y$. When the bug is at the point $(2,1)$, it is moving in such a way that its vertical velocity, $\dfrac{dy}{dt}$, is equal to $6$. What is its horizontal velocity, $\dfrac{dx}{dt}$, at that time?

My confusion with this that it doesn't look at all like the related rates problems I've seen, so I'm having trouble getting started.

Comment: Hint: Take the implicit derivative with respect to $t$.

Answer (score 1):

The bug is crawling along the curve given by the equation $x^2=y^3+3y$ means that we have functions $x(t)$ and $y(t)$ so that:

- At time $t$, the bug's position is $(x(t),y(t))$.
- $(x(t))^2=(y(t))^3+3y(t)$.

This is a related rate problem due to the relationship between $x(t)$ and $y(t)$ above.  By taking the derivative of both sides with respect to $t$, you get:

> $$2x(t)\frac{dx}{dt}=(3y(t)^2+3)\frac{dy}{dt}$$

Now, try to finish the problem with the given information.

Comment: I was able to solve it? Thank you for helping me to set it up!